# Codemirror displaying incorrectly due to CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, codemirror

My CSS code is causing Codemirror to display incorrectly. See below:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I prevent my styles from affecting the elements created by Codemirror so that Codemirror will display correctly?

Even if I manage to tweak my CSS code so that both my page and Codemirror display correctly, it will be a nightmare in the future because any future styles may affect Codemirror. Also my CSS file is generated dynamically depending on values given by the client, which further complicates things.

One possible solution is to create a `class` called `not-codemirror` and apply it to every single element on my site, other than elements for Codemirror. This seems like overkill to me, especially considering most pages will not be using Codemirror. All pages share the same CSS file.

Also, I would prefer a non-jQuery solution, if possible. Thanks

EDIT

I now have it displaying as this:

[image]

It should look like this:

[image]

I added:

```
display: inline;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
```

to `.CodeMirror span` in `codemirror.css`.

Comment: Do you know which of your elements is interfering with the codemirror elements? If your CSS naming convention is not completely bound by dynamic generation, you may be able to just selectively switch your element tag calls from `#id` to `.class` or something simple like that.

Comment: Most of my elements do not have an ID nor a class. I only give an ID or class, when JavaScript needs to interact with them or their style needs to be different to the other elements of the same type.

Comment: Although it may be time-consuming, I think it would be helpful for you to test for which of them is causing the interference and deal with each individually, rather than going with the nuclear option of `not-codemirror` for the entire site.

Comment: @Nez You might be right, but what I'm hoping to do is prevent Codemirror from using the styles, so then I can use whatever styles I like for the rest of my site.

Comment: Have you thought about hosting a copy of the Codemirror styling locally and changing the values that way?

Comment: I am hosting it locally and as it happens I'm looking through that file now and thinking about what I can change.

Comment: Great, I think you'll be happier that way. I am going to craft a formal answer if that's okay.

Comment: @Nez I've almost solved the problem by doing what you said. I'll let you post the answer so you can have the reputation points. Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codemirror markup has a specific class `.CodeMirror` (at least in latest version it's present);

So if you want other styles not to clash you can use [.not](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) :

```
clashing-selector:not(.CodeMirror)
```

Comment: This is a much better answer than mine.

Answer (score 1):

You know the problem lies in conflicting CSS declarations, so I would suggest giving each of yours or Codemirror's tags which are conflicting a `class` to clear up confusion. It's pretty clear that Codemirror should be the one you change since it sounds like you are fairly well bound by your site's dynamic CSS. This 'targeted' solution is a lot simpler than attacking your entire site with `not-codemirror` tags (and thankfully, does not involve any jQuery), and I don't think it will be that difficult to figure out what to change in Codemirror's source if you are relatively familiar with your own CSS.

If it turns out you run into issues with specificity as well, you may be able to justify using an `!important` tag, but I would try to stay away from that on principle.